# Calling curl to delete file from ftp in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, curl, delete-file, ftps

Im trying to delete a remote file from ftps calling curl from python 3.6 and keep getting errors from curl.
Im running

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-v", "-u", ftp_user+":"+ftp_pass, "-k", "--ftp-ssl", "--tlsv1.2", "--ftp-ssl-reqd", "--ftp-pasv", ftpconn, "-Q", '\"DELE '+remote_path+'/'+file+'\"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=120)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    proc.kill()
```

ftpconn is the address of the ftp server

in the response im getting this error:

```
curl: (21) QUOT command failed with 500
```

other operations on that ftps using curl, like list, download, upload etc. work fine.
i have tried single quotes, double quotes all same result.
when running from shell the delete works perfectly.
this is the full output of the curl process from stdout:

> - TCP_NODELAY set   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:--
>     --:--:--     0* Connected to ******************** port 21 (#0)
>
> } [5 bytes data]
>   * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1): } [167 bytes data]
>   * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2): { [85 bytes data]
>   * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11): { [4494 bytes data]
>   * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12): { [333 bytes data]
>   * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14): { [4 bytes data]
>   * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16): } [70 bytes data]
>   * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1): } [1 bytes data]
>   * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20): } [16 bytes data]
>   * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20): { [16 bytes data]
>   * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
>   * Server certificate:
>   *  start date: Sep  4 00:00:00 2017 GMT
>   *  expire date: Aug 25 23:59:59 2019 GMT
>   *  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
>   *  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway. } [5 bytes data]
>
> 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01
>   --:--:--     0{ [5 bytes data]
>
> } [5 bytes data]
>
> { [5 bytes data]
>
> } [5 bytes data]
>
> 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01
>   --:--:--     0{ [5 bytes data]
>
> } [5 bytes data]
>
> { [5 bytes data]
>
> } [5 bytes data]
>
> { [5 bytes data]
>
> - Entry path is '/' } [5 bytes data]
> - ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0 { [5 bytes data]
> - QUOT command failed with 500   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
> - Closing connection 0 } [5 bytes data]
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1): } [2 bytes data] curl: (21) QUOT command failed with 500
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Doesn't the -v option give you a lot of information about the transaction and where it went wrong?

Comment: Does the command work directly from the command-line?

Comment: the command works directly from command line